# How to fill QStandardItemModel with bigdata if setItem works slow?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

My task is to fill QStandardItemModel with some rect-shaped bigdata. The Python code is

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
import time


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(540, 220)
        self.table_view = QTableView(self)
        self.table_view.setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 200)
        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.move(420, 20)
        self.button.setText('Generate!')

        self.table_model = QStandardItemModel(parent=self)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self):
        start_time = time.time()

        start_cell = [2, 1]

        for i in range(100):
            for j in range(1000):
                item = QStandardItem('X')
                self.table_model.setItem(start_cell[0] + i, start_cell[1] + j, item)

        self.table_view.setModel(self.table_model)

        print(time.time() - start_time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For the first time it works pretty fast (0.2 s at my computer) but for the second time it takes 10s because QTableView is connected with QStandardItemModel `self.table_view.setModel(self.table_model)`

Could you advice how to disconnect QTableView and QStandardItemModel and if the more optimal way to fill table with bigdata?

===

Thanks to @musicamante the following code was realized. Now table is filled with `insertRow()` and now it takes ~0.4 sec.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
import time


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(540, 220)
        self.table_view = QTableView(self)
        self.table_view.setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 200)
        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.move(420, 20)
        self.button.setText('Paste bigdata')

        self.table_model = QStandardItemModel(parent=self)
        self.table_view.setModel(self.table_model)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                self.table_model.setItem(i, j, QStandardItem(str(10 * i + j)))

    def button_clicked(self):
        start_time = time.time()

        start_row = 2  # coordinates of bigdata array top-left corner
        start_col = 2
      
        for i in range(100):  # number of rows in bigdata array
            row = []
            # Adding cells before array
            for j in range(start_col):
                if self.table_model.item(start_row + i, j) is not None:
                    row.append(QStandardItem(self.table_model.item(start_row + i, j).text()))
                else:
                    row.append(QStandardItem(''))
            # Adding array cells
            for j in range(1000):  # number of columns in bigdata array
                row.append(QStandardItem('X'))
            # Adding cells after array
            for j in range(start_col + 1000, self.table_model.columnCount()-1, 1):
                if self.table_model.item(start_row + i, j) is not None:
                    row.append(QStandardItem(self.table_model.item(start_row + i, j).text()))
                else:
                    row.append(QStandardItem(''))

            self.table_model.insertRow(start_row + i, row)
            self.table_model.removeRows(start_row + i + 1, 1)

        print(time.time() - start_time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: First of all, you could start using [`appendRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#appendRow) instead of `setItem()` (make a temporary list at the beginning of the first for, append items in the second, and then call `appendRow` after that); alternatively, if it's still slow, consider setting (increasing) the row count *before* the for loops when using `setItem()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought about it, but I was afraid of a significant code increasing )) Anyway I've realized your suggestion (maybe in nonideal way) and now it takes 0.4s. It's quite strange for me that `row.append(self.table_model.item(i, j))` doesn't work properly and I have to use `row.append(QStandardItem(self.table_model.item(i, j).text()))`.

Comment: Please don't add a possible answer to a question, as it makes it confusing. Use the "Answer your question" button instead. In any case, after reading again the original code in your question I now see that you're actually overwriting the current model, but your new code is very confusing. What are you trying to achieve? If the model already has items set, you should not set new ones, but use `setData()` instead, but your nested `for` loops don't make a lot of sense anyway. Please try to clarify what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Actually, I want to copy-paste clipboard content from Excel to arbitrary place of QStandardItemModel that already contains some data. That's why in the second example some data (10 x 10) are generated before. After it bigdata array (100 x 1000) is pasted in position (2, 2). 1st code does the similar action, but w/o generating initial data and with `setData()`.

Comment: Did you solve it? same here ... , actually I have it in Qt/C++ . freezing gui when setting new data for a while.